# MERGE Command in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, merge, insert

I have been using the statement

```
insert into target 
select * from source 
where [set of conditions] for a while.
```

Recently found this MERGE command that will be more effective to use for my purpose so that I can change the above statement to

```
MERGE target 
USING source ON [my condtion] 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
THEN INSERT VALUES (source.col1, source.col2, source.col3)
```

But the problem for me is lets say if I have 20+ columns in my source table I have to list all of them, I need a way to specify it to insert source.* . Is there a way ? I'm new to SQL. Appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me too; I hate typing column names.

I normally build the Merge statement in dynamic SQL.
I have a function that takes a table name as a parameter, and returns a string containing all column names formatted properly with Table Name prefix, [] brackets and comma, as in S.Col1, S.Col2, S.Col3

I could also tell you that I build a temp table with the required columns, and pass the temp table to my function, because some times you don't want a list of all columns. But that would probably be a confusing wooble, obscuring the important bits;

1. Use dynamic sql
2. Use a function to create csv list of columns.

Comment: hmm.. this'd make things easier.. 'll try this out.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that I have read regarding the `MERGE` statement says that you need to specify the columns for your `INSERT` statement.  If you are looking for a quick way to get the `INSERT` statment, you can right mouse click the table in SSMS and select Script Table As->INSERT To->Clipboard.  You can then paste this into your query and alter just the `VALUES` part.

[Merge statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There's simply no advantage of using MERGE in this situation. Why overcomplicate? Stick to the KISS principle, for chrissake.

Anyways, here's the script:

```
declare 
    @targetTableName varchar(100) = 'target'
    ,@targetSchemaName varchar(20) = 'dbo'
    ,@sourceTableName varchar(100) = 'source'
    ,@sourceSchemaName varchar(20) = 'dbo2'
    ,@matchCondition varchar(50) = 't.id = s.id'
    ,@columns varchar(max)

set @columns = (select ','+quotename(c.name)
from sys.tables t 
join sys.columns as c on t.object_id = c.object_id
join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
where t.name = @targetTableName and s.name = isnull(@targetSchemaName, s.name)
for xml path(''))

--a column name starts with a comma

declare @sql varchar(max) =  '
merge @target t 
using @source s on @matchCondition
when not matched then 
insert (@columns)
values @sourceColumns'

set @sql = 
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(@sql
, '@matchCondition', @matchCondition)
 --replace @columns with column list with the first comma removed
, '@columns', stuff(@columns, 1, 1, ''))
--replace @sourceColumns with column list with the 's.' prefix and comma removed
, '@sourceColumns', stuff(replace(@columns, ',', ',s.'),1,1,''))
, '@target', quotename(@targetSchemaName)+'.'+quotename(@targetTableName))
, '@source', quotename(@sourceSchemaName)+'.'+quotename(@sourceTableName))

print @sql
--exec(@sql)
```

And we'll get something like this:

```
merge [dbo].[target] t 
using [dbo2].[source] s on t.id = s.id
when not matched then 
insert ([column1], [column2], [column3], [column4])
values s.[column1], s.[column2], s.[column3], s.[column4]
```

Comment: Denis- Nope, I found it a lot more optimized way.
I had a 5 lakh+ rows in my source table which caused the 1st query to run for about 45-50 minutes. The change to MERGE command made it complete in seconds :-D :-D So I definitely need a change.

Comment: This just doesn't make any sense. MERGE reduced to simple INSERT cannot perform better or worse than the latter. I can't just wrap my head around of what you just said. :D

Comment: As to the long-running query, did you try to specify "with(nolock)" on the source table? And believe me, MERGE just can't perform THAT better.